# Apache NiFi: Migrate data from MSSQL to MySql

Tags: apache-nifi

Is there any tutorial or guide to migrate data from MSSQL to MySQL or any other database?

I am trying to migrate data from MSSQL to MySQL using apache NiFi with some modification in data + schema.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43863511/transfer-data-from-vertica-to-redshift-using-apache-nifi/43873694#43873694) for my answer for migrating between two different RDBMS in Apache NiFi. You may need some extra processors such as a [JoltTransformJSON](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.2.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON/index.html) after the ConvertAvroToJSON processor, to make the schema/data changes.