# Transfer data from vertica to Redshift using Apache Nifi

Tags: amazon-redshift, vertica, apache-nifi

I want to transfer data from vertica to redshift using apache nifi.
which  are the processors and configuration I need to set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If Vertica and Redshift have "well-behaved" JDBC drivers, you can set up a [DBCPConnectionPool](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool/index.html) for each, then a SQL processor such as [ExecuteSQL](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL/index.html), [QueryDatabaseTable](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryDatabaseTable/index.html), or [GenerateTableFetch](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GenerateTableFetch/index.html) (the latter of which generates SQL for use in ExecuteSQL). These will get your records into Avro format, then (prior to NiFi 1.2.0) you can use [ConvertAvroToJSON](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.avro.ConvertAvroToJSON/index.html) -> [ConvertJSONToSQL](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ConvertJSONToSQL/index.html) -> [PutSQL](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL/index.html) to get your records inserted into Redshift.

In NiFi 1.2.0, you can use set up an AvroReader for use in PutDatabaseRecord. Then you will only need the SQL processor to get the records out of Vertica, directly to PutDatabaseRecord to put them into Redshift.

Comment: Has anyone tried this yet? Can PutSQL generate 10000 rows batch insert if we would like to insert million row?

Comment: links in the answer are dead - info can be found here: https://nifi.apache.org/docs.html

Comment: You can now replace ConvertAvroToJSON -> ConvertJSONToSQL -> PutSQL with PutDatabaseRecord, you should see much better performance than the aforementioned flow.